# What's there to know about Verizon FiOS Speed?

Tags: internet-connection, bandwidth, fios

I'm working on getting a separate internet connection to run out and I was looking into available options.

FiOS claims to offer 25Mb up / 25 Mb down *as a maximum rate*.

Do they have listed minimum rates? Is there anything with fiber I should be concerned about? Special hardware, special routers, availability concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you can't get a minimum rate guarantee on a residential line. That is one of the main perks of the more expensive business lines.

As for special equipment, it is terminated differently, but Verizon provides the fiber equivalent of a modem and from there it's all copper Ethernet, so your existing routers, etc will be fine. The availability concern is one that would be specific to Verizon, not to fiber. Fiber is widely used and is a reliable medium for data transmission.

Comment: Old but still worthy... Verizon will look at issues if your not getting at least 80% of what you are provisioned for.

Answer (score 0):

They have a plan that says 25Mbps both directions for $64.99.  What they can actually deliver depends upon how their network was built.  They might have to down limit you to keep you at or under 25Mbps.  Read the fine print.

Whenever you hear speeds quoted it is based upon max frame size being transmitted.  In reality all internet traffic is a variety of packet sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Verizon, but do have fiber into my home.  I've tried 3 different plans (35 down/10 up, 20/5, and 7/1), and they all deliver at least the stated speeds, at least according to speedtest.net.  Upload speeds are a bit higher than promised, usually around 10-15%.

Comment: Download and upload speeds can be sometimes a bit higher than promised, but that's not necessary a feature. It can rather be a consequence of the way the shaper works. You get a higher speed than maximum for some time just because the upper pipe is not saturated, over time you get lower speed, so the average stays pretty close to the maximum limit.